# $\int\limits_0^\pi \sin(x) \sin(n x) dx$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The integral

> $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \sin (nx) \, dx. $$

Note that I think the solution should be $0$. I solved every integral of the following by parts.

\begin{align*}
\int (\sin x)(\sin nx) \, dx
&= (-\cos x)(\sin (nx)) - \int (-\cos x)(n\cos nx) \, dx \\
&= (-\cos x)(\sin (nx)) + n\int (\cos x)(\cos nx) \, dx
\end{align*}

The last integral is

\begin{align*}
\int (\cos x) (\cos (nx) ) \, dx
&= (\sin x)(\cos (nx)) - \int (\sin x)(n\sin (nx)) \, dx \\
&= (\sin x)(\cos (nx)) - n\int (\sin x)(\sin (nx)) \, dx.
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
&&\int (\sin x)(\sin nx) \, dx &= (-\cos x)(\sin (nx))-n(\sin x)(\cos (nx)) \\
&& & \qquad - n^2\int (\sin x)(\sin (nx)) \, dx, \\
\implies &&
(1-n^2)\int (\sin x)(\sin {nx}) \, dx &= (-\cos x)(\sin (nx))-n(\sin x)(\cos (nx)) \\
\implies &&
\int (\sin x)(\sin (nx)) \, dx &= \frac{(-\cos x)(\sin (nx))-n(\sin x)(\cos (nx))}{1-n^2}
\end{align*}

Then the integral is

$$ \int (\sin x)(\sin (nx)) \, dx = (-\cos x)(\sin (nx))-n(\sin (x))(\cos (nx)) $$

And taking the integration limits I have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi (\sin x)(\sin (nx)) \, dx
&= (1-n^2)^{-1} (-\cos x)(\sin (nx))-n(\sin (x))(\cos (nx)) \bigg|_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= (1-n^2)^{-1} \Big( [ \cos(\pi)\sin(n\pi) - n(\sin (\pi)(\cos(n\pi)))]   \\
&\hspace{8em} - [\cos(0)\sin(0) - n(\sin (0)(\cos(0)))] \Big) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: The result is false. It is very hard to follow your arguments.

Comment: You should look at $n=1$ and $n\neq 1$ separatly.

Comment: I edited your answer so that it has better formatting, but did not attempt to fix any computation mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi}\sin x\sin nx dx$$
If $n=1$, one has $$I_1 = \int_0^\pi \sin ^2xdx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi (1-\cos 2x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\pi.$$

If $n\neq 1$, one has $$I_n = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi (\cos (n+1)x-\cos(n-1)x)dx$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sin(n+1)x-\frac{1}{n-1}\sin(n-1)x\right)\bigg\vert_0^\pi$$
I left you to verify the result.

Comment: Isn't the solution still zero? because $\sin(n+1)x$ and $\sin(n-1)x$ will be $0$ since $\sin n\pi = \sin 0 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$\sin(x)\sin(nx)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(x-nx)-\cos(x+nx)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos((n-1)x)-\cos((n+1)x))\right)$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sin(nx)dx=\frac12\int_0^\pi \cos((n-1)x)dx-\frac12\int_0^\pi \cos((n+1)x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y = x - \pi/2$, notice the symmetric limits and find directly:

If $n=1:  \pi/2$.  If $n \neq 1:  0$.

(Graphing makes it obvious.)